# Using Metro UI CSS for Windows 8 App

Tags: html, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, winjs, metro-ui-css

I'm looking into if it's possible to use the Metro UI CSS framework to develop windows 8 apps. I understand i can have what ever CSS that's needed but i think it's based on the bootstrap framework so im unsure if its compatible?

I forgot to include a link to it: http://metroui.org.ua/

Comment: I've never developed WWA apps, but why wouldn't that work? Have you tried?

Comment: I'll certainly give it a try, I had read that bootstrap wouldn't work with it so assumed this wouldn't. Unsure on how things like PPI would affect it

Answer (score 0):

If you use everything locally I don't see a reason why it would not work. Just make sure you add all the references (css and js) they need.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/metro-bootstrap.css">
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.widget.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/metro/metro.min.js"></script>
```